# Converting code with Anonymous functions to PHP 5.2

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I have some PHP 5.3 code which builds an array to be passed to a view. This is the code I have.

```
# Select all this users links.
$data = $this->link_model->select_user_id($this->user->id);
if (count($data) > 0) {
    # Process the data into the table format.
    $table = array
    (
        'properties' => array
        (
            'delete_link_column' => 0,
        ),
        'callbacks' => array
        (
            # Callback for the name link.
            function($value) {
                return sprintf('<a href="/links/view/name/%s">%s</a>', $value, $value);
            },
            # Callback for the category link.
            function($value) {
                return sprintf('<a href="/category/view/name/%s">%s</a>', $value, $value);
            },
            # Callback for the creation date.
            function($value) {
                return date('jS M Y', $value);
            },
            # Callback for the delete link.
            function($value) {
                return sprintf('<a href="links/delete/name/%s">delete</a>', $value);
            },
        ),
        'columns' => array
        (
            'name', 'category', 'creation date',
        ),
        'data' => array
        (

        ),
        'sorting' => array
        (
            'sort' => false,
        ),
    );
```

However the problem is that I cannot use anonymous functions in PHP 5.2, which is the server I must upload this schoolwork. The view requires callback functions to be defined so it can call them.

What would be the neatest way to convert this PHP code to not using anonymous functions? Thanks.

Comment: When and how and why are theses callbacks called?

Comment: @deceze This array is passed to a view which processes the array and creates a table from the data. The callbacks are called for the data in each column to format the data.

So if a table cell value was 'Boats' in the first column, the view would process that into the value '<a href="/links/view/name/Boats">Boats</a>

I didn't really want to change the view because I have alot of controllers using it like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could call one of those function like so:

```
$func = $callbacks[0];
$func();
```

Which also works with [`create_function()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) and using strings for named functions like so:

```
function test() {
  echo "test";
}
$func = 'test';
$func();

$func = create_function('' , 'echo "test 2"; ');
$func();
```

Also, if the calling is done using [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) you can use `array($object, 'func_name')` to call a public method on an object or a class with `array('Class_Name', 'func_name')`:

```
class Test {
  public static function staticTest() { echo "Static Test"; }
  public function methodTest() { echo "Test"; }

  public function runTests() {
    $test = array('Test', 'staticTest');
    call_user_func($test);

    $test = array($this, 'methodTest');
    call_user_func($test);
  }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->runTests();
```

Answer (score 7):

Anonymous functions are great for ephemeral one-offs, like event listeners in patterns like Observer.

However, since you've already formalized an interface (callbacks for rendering names, categories, creation dates, and a delete link) you may as well go the extra step of defining a 'renderer' interface that requires those 4 methods to be implemented.  Instead of passing callbacks you'd pass a single renderer subclass to the view, which could then be used to call the appropriate methods.  The view could also validate it by checking the parent class.  That would still allow you to swap renderers in the spirit of portable, reusable OOP without requiring anonymous functions.

Is there a situation where your callbacks would ever be coming from arbitrary code (e.g. plugins)?  If not, there's really no benefit to making those callbacks anonymous.  It might seem like you're saving a little namespace bloat, but you're also making it tougher to debug or document.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a cleaner OOP method... Could maybe use a source example?

Comment: I Jeff, thanks for the answer, what you are saying makes alot of sense. Sorry I didn't mark your answer as correct, both answers I've received are correct (and next time I would do it the way you are talking about).

Comment: No problem! I'm glad we could both help. :)

Comment: @Jeff, To do it this way, we effectively need to create one new subclass **per** anonymous function. This is unmaintainable and pointless unless there's a way to do anonymous classes.

Comment: @gnarf, There's a reason why there are no source examples. It's because this method is **not clean** at all. This essentially requires you to create a new subclass for each callback. So if you need 10 callbacks, you will need to create 10 new classes `SubClass1` to `SubClass10`.

Comment: @Pacerier The number of subclasses isn't Θ(n).  You'd just need a subclass per distinct unit of functionality.  In the original examples provided by @NeedsEducation, he needs methods for rendering abstract links and dates.  There are three kinds of links: name, category, and delete.  So he'd only need renderNameLink(), renderCategoryLink(), renderDeleteLink(), and renderDate() as methods.  Since he's only passing a `$value` to the links methods, he could get away with just `renderLink($value)` as well.

Comment: @JeffStanden,  That's just one example he had raised. In any non-trivial app you'll be able to find over hundreds of anonymous functions. That means that using your solution we need to declare over hundreds of new subclasses. Not a good idea.

Comment: @Pacerier It's probably moot.  The original post and comment you resurrected are nearly 5 years old.  I'd be surprised if OP is still stuck on PHP 5.3 without anonymous functions at this point.  Nobody disagrees that anonymous functions / closures are useful for abstraction, but the question prohibited them as a solution.  create_function() doesn't avoid the concern you have.  My point remains that OP likely would have been better off by refactoring the code for OOP/MVC. Hundreds of anonymous functions may be emblematic of design issues as well.

Comment: @JeffStanden, Hundreds of anonymous functions is definitely not a design issue. Indeed doing code the functional way **requires** hundreds of anonymous functions. `create_function` **does avoid** having to assign names to the functions. The only ungracefulness is that the body needs to be a string, otherwise it works totally fine. Also,  [code](http://goo.gl/DsFOjF) has a [surprisingly long](http://goo.gl/pXvtW5) lifetime and more than just often features are appended onto old code. So don't be surprised that this question is still valid now and well into the future, it's **far from moot**.

Comment: @Pacerier I'm sure we agree that if someone is heavily relying on functional programming patterns in PHP then they should be using version 5.3+ with anonymous functions.  The workarounds stated here for 5.2 were a relevant issue 5 years ago, but not now.  Nobody advocated these answers as a best practice.  Given the widespread availability of anonymous functions in PHP these days, everything else we're talking about here regarding a hypothetical world without them is moot.