# syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION on "use" operator

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use PHP closure function like function() use() on PHP 5.2 version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282066/how-can-i-use-php-closure-function-like-function-use-on-php-5-2-version)

I'm trying to run this on a server that's running php 5.2.

```
function add_post_type($name, $args = array() ) {
add_action('init',function() use($name, $args) { 

    // execute custom post type code here

});
};
```

The 2nd line is throwing an unexpected T_FUNCTION error, I suspect its cause of the "use" operator. Can someone help point me as to how I can rewrite this function to run in php 5.2?

Comment: I guess it is because you haven't specified curly braces after `function()`.   but what actually you are trying to do?

Comment: @Hafiz I'm making a custom post type helper function to put in my functions.php file in my wordpress theme. Makes making CPTs faster and more convenient. Followed this from a tutorial a while ago. As for te curly braces, it comes after the "use($name,$args)" as that statement as i understand it makes the variables available to the function below. anyway it runs fine on my MAMP which has PHP 5.3. my production has 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this function:-

/* Add Post Type */

```
function wpse54191_plugin_init() {
add_post_type('Netherlands', array(
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments')
));
}
add_action('init', 'wpse54191_plugin_init');

/* Add Post Type */
function add_post_type($name, $args = array() ) {   
    if ( !isset($name) ) return;

    $name = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $name));
    $args = array_merge(
        array(
            'label' => 'Members ' . ucwords($name) . '',
            'labels' => array('add_new_item' => "Add New $name"),
            'singular_name' => $name,
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'comments'),
        ),
        $args
    );

    register_post_type( $name, $args);
}
```

Comment: Awesome this looks good, will try it right away

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems to provide a good solution for what you're trying to do in PHP 5.2: converting anonymous functions to user-defined functions.

[Converting Code with Anonymous functions to PHP 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809405/converting-code-with-anonymous-functions-to-php-5-2)

Good luck! And try and upgrade your PHP version :P

Comment: Thanks, looks like i have to catch up on that topic. Im on a shared hosting package without access to the WHM or shell, so I dont think I can upgrade it myself.